# Fibbonacci sequence using for loop java

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me how to store the previous two fibbonnaci numbers it would help alot in this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++) {

        if (k > 2) {
            k = (k - 1) + (k - 2);
        }
        System.out.print(k+" ");
        k++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What your code needs could hardly be described as "fixing". It needs *rethinking* and rewriting from scratch, just to start resembling an attempt at a solution.

Comment: Use two variables to store the previous Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I disagree that the question is unclear.  Is it a good question?  Well, that's what downvotes are for.  But it's not necessarily unclear.

Comment: @Makoto Do you think it shouldn't have been closed, or that it was closed with the wrong reason? Often with questions like this, one is at a loss where to fit it in the "close reason" array. "Too broad" works for me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:  I'd like to avoid a long, drawn out debate about it here - I may post something about it on Meta later - but what I'm saying is that the question doesn't necessarily warrant closure.  It may warrant downvotes - that, I'm not arguing against - but not closure.  Shoehorning a closure reason because one is "at a loss" as to which one to use is at best an abuse of the closure system.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe it's the closure system which is to blame :) Anyway, in this particular case, since the question essentially asks to provide a complete solution to a stated problem, as opposed to fixing an inadequate solution, I don't see any controversy in closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you got number 5 as the printed out put you will set k++ ,  that will make k=6.
after that `k = (k - 1) + (k - 2);` output  k = (6-1)+(6-2) = 5+4 = 9 , (note : the next should be 8 so your algorithm is wrong)

You have mistaken the Idea of Fibonacci numbers.

the nth Fibonacci  number is equal to the sum of previous two Fibonacci  numbers. not to the (Fn-1)+(Fn-2)

**Edited :** 
So as you can see if we know the first 2 Fibonacci  numbers we can calculate the third by adding those two. and the fourth one will be the summation of second one and third one and it goes ..... to n.

Okay here is a way that you don't need a recursive approach ( you need to store the found Fibonacci  numbers in an Array)

okay assume you want to find first **n** Fibonacci  numbers. then create an array of size **n** and set first and second elements to one (1) since **first two Fibonacci  numbers are 1 and 1**. now loop through the array from **2 to n**. at each iteration add the previous two element to the next element. 
go through the code. you will  find it very easy to do.

```
 public static void fib(int n){

    int Fibonacci [] = new int[n];
    Fibonacci [0]=1;
    Fibonacci [1]=1;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {

        Fibonacci [i]=Fibonacci [i-1]+Fibonacci [i-2];

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Fibonacci ));
}
```

Comment: how could i store the previous two fibonnacci numbers and then add them together. Thanks a lot for your help I am relatively new to coding.